# Batch: Compare Dir list txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file

Windows 7/8/10 (x86/x64)
Window Batch

Hi all,

Firstly, the task I have been given:

A music library drive is backed up to a secondary drive every day using Robocopy.
Due to the possibility of deleting a file on the music library, **the two cannot be mirror clones**.  Only different/new files are copied over to the backup drive.

Sometimes, it is discovered that a file(s) are in an incorrect folder on the music library and are moved to their correct folder.  When the backup script is engaged, it then copies these 'new' files and their 'new' folder to the backup drive.  The backup drive then has two copies of the file(s), one in it's correct 'new' position in the tree, and the other is the old erroneous one.  The old is an unwanted duplicate.

I have so far managed to script the following:

1. Run through the latest Robocopy Log file (RClog), converting source file path to correct path on the backup drive.  So it can be compared.
2. DIR the backup drive and dump to text file.
3. Put the converted RClog into an 'array' of variables.
4. Run through each line in the DIR list and compare the filename against the array.  If it's a match, see if the full path matches.  If not a fullpath match, then it's a possible* duplicate.  Output full path to txt file.

So, I have my current code below.
It is painfully slow however.  I think this is because I am performing close to 1 million actions! There are around 10k mp3 files, and about 100 newly copied files in the RClog.

I am thinking that I need to start, instead, with the smaller list of file, the RClog, and find those files in the DIR_List of the backup drive.  However, I notice that FINDSTR doesn't like backlashes and needs them escaping.  This would require a FOR loop to do variable substring substitution, which could slow things down some for both lists.

There is a final task I must perform, and that will be to MD5 hash the proposed unwanted duplicate file, and see if it's the same as the newly copied.  *It could be that it happens to share the same name, but be from a different artist, so that needs to be checked.  Some human intervention will likely be required at some point here, but for the most part automation is key, and quicker automation.

Whilst **I really would prefer to keep this pure batch without 3rd party tools**, I would consider using PowerShell as long as it's up to v3.0.  I don't want to have to update things on the systems, and force changes.  I am trying to work with what is there, and pure batch is available.

I apologise in advance for the rather casual commenting style.

Thanks in advance for any contributions.

```
::@ECHO OFF

@ECHO:
@ECHO: ===========================================================
@ECHO:
@ECHO:         Music_library backup duplicate files finder
@ECHO:
@ECHO: Finds duplicate files to those included in the specified
@ECHO: robocopy log and lists them in a text file on the desktop
@ECHO:
@ECHO: ===========================================================
@ECHO:


:: Define Duplicates log
    SET "DUPE_CHECK_LOG=%userprofile%\desktop\duplicates_log.txt"

:: Define Directory to scan
    SET "IN_DIR=U:\Backups\Music_Library"

:: Define temporary DIR txt file
SET "TMP_DIR_TXT=%TMP%\Temp_Dir_list.txt"

:: FOR THE ROBOCCOPY LOG COPIED FILE PATH CONVERTER
:: Define Temporary robocopy log converted path file
    SET "TMP_RC=%TMP%\Temp_RC_Conv.txt"

:: Define common root folder between both locations
:: copied from (in the Rc log) and backup location.
    SET "CommonSplit=\Digital_Music_Library\"
:: END SECTION

:: Put rc log file path into a variable for easier reading
    SET /P "RC_LOG=Drag and drop desired Robocopy Log here > "


:: strip rc log down to name.ext only
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a IN ("%RC_LOG%") DO SET "RC_LOG_name=%%~nxa"

:: Print rc log name to new entry in dupes log
    (
    @ECHO:
    @ECHO:  %RC_LOG_name%
    )>>"%DUPE_CHECK_LOG%"

:: Debug
::PAUSE

:: Delete old converted robocopy log if present
    IF EXIST "%TMP_RC%" DEL /Q "%TMP_RC%"

:: Delete old dir txtif present
    IF EXIST "%TMP_DIR_TXT%" DEL /Q "%TMP_DIR_TXT%"

:: Convert Robocopy Log to a list of those files in their new location
:: on the target drive.  RC log lists 'from' location not 'to', so all
:: files wouldn't share the same path - different drive altogether.
:: Need to string path of copied files down to a common root folder 
:: between the two locations.  eg. Digital_Music_Library

FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=    " %%a IN ('FINDSTR /C:"New File" "%RC_LOG%"') DO (
CALL :RC_CONVERTER "%%~fa"
)

:: Debug
::PAUSE

:: Take all of the data from text file and jam it into an array of variables
:: Each number of the var corresponds to that line in the text file...sheesh!
:: One var name for full path, the other for filenameext.
:: I just don't want yet another FOR loop to play with paramters/arguments - eg. %%~dpnxa
:: Shove this bit after the RC log is created, but really before anything else.
:: EnableDelayedExpansion must persist, can't ENDLOCAL on it yet, as it'll clear the var array!

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET /A i=0
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN ("%TMP_RC%") DO (
    SET /A i+=1
    SET "ArrayFullPath[!i!]=%%~fa"
    SET "ArrayFilenameExt[!i!]=%%~nxa"
)

:: debug
::PAUSE



:: Dumps contents of music library into a txt file, all mp3s.
DIR /b/s "%IN_DIR%\*.mp3">>"%TMP_DIR_TXT%"

:: Loop through each line in Dir.txt checking if file is dupe
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%a IN ("%TMP_DIR_TXT%") DO (
CALL :CHECKER "%%~fa"
REM PAUSE
)


:: End out commands

:: Delete old converted robocopy log if present
    IF EXIST "%TMP_RC%" DEL /Q "%TMP_RC%"

:: Delete old dir txtif present
    IF EXIST "%TMP_DIR_TXT%" DEL /Q "%TMP_DIR_TXT%"

@ECHO:
@ECHO: Finished finding duplicates.
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
GOTO :EOF


:CHECKER
:: Start at 1 and go to the maximum number of array vars created earlier.
:: For each one compare the found filename.ext from above against the filename.ext in the array
:: If it matches, make sure the path doesn't, and then print full path to duplicate file to a text file.
:: End subroutine and go back for the next found file.
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%i%) DO (
    IF /I "!ArrayFilenameExt[%%a]!" == "%~nx1" (
        IF /I NOT "!ArrayFullPath[%%a]!" == "%~f1" (
            FOR /F "tokens=*" %%z IN ("%~f1") DO (
                ECHO %%~fz>>"%DUPE_CHECK_LOG%"
                )
            )
        )
)
EXIT /B

:RC_CONVERTER
:: Take the full path from the RC log sent as paramter/argument
:: Use variable substring substitution to remove everything before and 
:: including the common folder.
:: Print out to text file target drive, path, common folder and remaining path of 
:: copied files.
    SET "TMP_STR=%~f1"
    CALL SET "TempStr=%%TMP_STR:*%CommonSplit%=%%"
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g in ("%TempStr%") DO (
    @ECHO %IN_DIR%%CommonSplit%%%~g>>"%TMP_RC%"
    )
EXIT /B
```

Comment: This question belongs on  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ rather.